# Get mouse position on Linux, pure Python

Tags: python, linux, mouse, x11

I'm trying to get the global mouse position `(x, y)` in Linux with pure Python (+ctypes if necessary). I can get relative position changes by listening to `/dev/input/mice`, but I'm not receiving any event with absolute position to calibrate (EV_ABS).

I tried using ctypes to connect to X11, but everything after `XOpenDisplay` segfaults (yes, the `XOpenDisplay` worked and returned non-zero):

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.util
x11 = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.util.find_library('X11'))
display = x11.XOpenDisplay(None)
assert display
window = x11.XDefaultRootWindow(display) # segfault here
```

The equivalent code works well in C, but I'm looking for a solution without dependencies or compilation steps:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

int main (){
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    XEvent event;
    XQueryPointer(display, XDefaultRootWindow(display),
        &event.xbutton.root, &event.xbutton.window,
        &event.xbutton.x_root, &event.xbutton.y_root,
        &event.xbutton.x, &event.xbutton.y,
        &event.xbutton.state);
    printf("%d %d\n", event.xbutton.x_root, event.xbutton.y_root);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 0;
}
```

This was tested on Fedora 23, 64 bits.

Comment: I have noticed this issue on Fedora 23 as well, except in my case, the segfault is on `XDefaultScreen()`, much to the same goal of getting the root window. I had asked on the Fedora IRC channel and had not had any success. In my case, my work around was to call into `xsetroot`, but your use case is different. You can see the full backtrace and code I used [here on GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/winny-/ea0aa1546def52241be4).

Comment: This might help: http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Robᵩ Interesting idea of using TCP-IP to talk to the X server. Unfortunately the latest version of this library has Python 1.5 (!) as requirement and zero mentions for "mouse".

Comment: FYI, OP's Python snippet runs to completion without segfault on Ubuntu 14.04.3.

Comment: As of 2016-06-06 the code above still segfaults on Fedora 23, 64 bits.

Comment: As of 2018-03-03 the code above still segfaults on Ubuntu 17.10, 64 bits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works for me with Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04.3. It is almost entirely copied from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16157/4836

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys
from ctypes import *
Xlib = CDLL("libX11.so.6")
display = Xlib.XOpenDisplay(None)
if display == 0: sys.exit(2)
w = Xlib.XRootWindow(display, c_int(0))
(root_id, child_id) = (c_uint32(), c_uint32())
(root_x, root_y, win_x, win_y) = (c_int(), c_int(), c_int(), c_int())
mask = c_uint()
ret = Xlib.XQueryPointer(display, c_uint32(w), byref(root_id), byref(child_id),
                         byref(root_x), byref(root_y),
                         byref(win_x), byref(win_y), byref(mask))
if ret == 0: sys.exit(1)
print child_id.value
print root_x, root_y
```

Edit: The following script, using python-xlib 0.12, prints the root window's mouse position:

```
from Xlib import display
qp = display.Display().screen().root.query_pointer()
print qp.root_x, qp.root_y
```

Comment: That's what I was trying to do, and segfaults on Fedora 23 64bits, probably related to @Winny's comment.

Comment: See my recent edit. Note that python-xlib supports 2,7, python3-xlib supports some version of python3.

Comment: Segfault were probably caused by wrong ctypes restype. To fix it, we can explicitly set the restype to c_void_p:

    `x11.XOpenDisplay.restype = ctypes.c_void_p`
    `display = ctypes.c_void_p(x11.XOpenDisplay(0))`

The following links show the similar problem in x-tile and a fix for it:
https://github.com/giuspen/x-tile/issues/2
https://github.com/giuspen/x-tile/commit/6f39fd88ed6c5bafadea1a056a52bfc9f62e14b4